# How to autoscale Kubernetes Pods based on average memory usage in EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, amazon-eks, hpa

I am running an [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) cluster and I have a [HorizontalPodAutoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) created for autoscaling number of pods based on average CPU utilisation.

How to do the same for Average memory utilization?

Suppose all of the pods running in an EKS clusters, have used average of 70% of memory they are allocated (using [resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)), then the deployment should be autoscaled.

How to do this? Is creating a custom metric in [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) the only way?

Even if cloudWatch is the only way, how to do that? Is there a specific documentation or tutorial or blog that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below `HPA` configuration object.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: nginx-hpa
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: nginx
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      targetAverageUtilization: 70
```

and apply the object using `kubectl apply`

Comment: this will never work. You can change the resource name to `wtf`, and it will go through, but it also will look for `wtf` metric.

Comment: @suren but CPU and memory metrics are provided by Kubernetes by default right. I am referring to [this](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-horizontal-pod-autoscaler/)

Comment: Suren, I really want to understand what's the problem with this object?

Comment: I am sorry. You are right. I just tested it and it worked. Had done this back in the days, and didn't work. My fault.

Comment: No problem Suren, I think it can be accepted as an answer then :)

Comment: Thanks @nischaygoyal and suren. I tried and it works fine.